# Random python selection within a ranged distribution

Tags: python, random, statistics

I have a normal distributed range from 10 to 100 with an average of 25. I am wanting to randomly sample this. Using:

```
random.gauss(25, 5)
```

I can obtain get a sample where the mean is 25 and the standard deviation is 6. Meaning only a 1% chance of getting outside of my lower limit. Obviously though this is not putting a high enough waiting on my upper limit and I will at most reach 40.

At present the only way I can think to hit the upper limit is to look at both the upper and lower with using a decision rule to look at the upper half 50% using

```
random.gauss(25, 25)
```

of the time and lower the other 50% and have the first snippet. Only consider values higher than the mean for the upper and lesser than the mean for the other.

Is there any other way I can make this anymore precise. I have seen online ways of skewing a normal distribution but unsure how I can get that to work as my stats really isn't that strong.

The distribution I want is something that looks like

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srHxy.jpg]

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

UPDATE:
After looking and agreeing with some I believe I need to ignore my initial idea as doesn't work and use

```
np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma)
```

but does anyone know how to set mu and sigma to what I need to represent?

Comment: This isn't going to be a normal distribution if the average isn't at the center of the range.  Do you know what you want the distribution to look like?  Do you want floating point samples or integer samples?

Comment: look like the skewed nature of the first graph here http://i.stack.imgur.com/srHxy.jpg

Comment: Looks like you want a log normal distribution `lognormvariate(mu, sigma)`, but I don't know how to set the mu and sigma to get you what you are looking for.

Comment: After looking at it seems that way yes, as you I don't know how to set up the mu and sigma

Comment: Seeing as mu typically refers to the mean in stats, you probably want to set mu = 25. I'm not sure about an appropriate value for sigma, though, or if one even exists that would produce the exact limits that you want.

Comment: Since the range is bounded, it looks more like a scaled and shifted [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) could be parameterized to fit your needs.  The lognormal has the positively skewed general shape you seem to be looking for, but goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

A beta distribution could fit the bounded range as suggested in a comment, but the shape of the density would not match what you want if you keep a mean of 25 and a standard deviation of 5.

You could try the lognormal (check Wikipedia to see how mu and sigma relate to the mean and variance). I found the following fit by matching those formulas numerically in Excel:

Let Y be a lognormal random variable with mu = 2.65537 and sigma = 0.324591 Let X = Y + 10. Then X is close to what you want - the mean of X is 25 and it has a standard deviation of 5. You are not going to observe many values of X above 40, though, since the standard deviation is only 5.